# My App version is higher than previous but getting Version issue

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

> "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString
>   [1.2] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that
>   of the previously approved version [1.15]. Please find more
>   information about CFBundleShortVersionString at
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"

Please guide me. is it funny or m not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that `CFBundleShortVersionString` is [1.2] which seems greater than [1.15] when you consider both as decimal values. But, versions are not calculated the same way. You might want to modify your version from [1.2] to [1.20] to make it higher than [1.15].